# How to print an array with different digits after the decimal point?

Tags: c

So I have an array that can hold all kind of numbers, negative, decimal, integer so I went with float, and I want to print it the same as I entered them but sorted in ascending order.
I did something like this

```
scanf("%d", &n);
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       scanf("%f", &a[i]);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]>a[j+1])
        {
            temp=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
printf("{%.1f", a[0]);
for(i= 1; i < n; i++)
{
    printf(", %.1f", a[i]);
}
printf("}");
}
```

But the problem here is: 1. I can't get the numbers to appear with same decimal digits as I entered them and 2. There is a comma after the last number
The number for examples are 1, -2, 3.4,-2.3, 0 and I want them to be like this {-2.3, -2, 0, 1, 3.4}
My sorting works excellent but I have these problems with the output.
Edit: Fixed the problem with commas, I just need to print out for example the number 3 as 3, and the number 3.4 only as 3.4 in the same for loop. Added the other part of the code.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. To deal with the comma, change the loop to print all numbers but the last, with a comma, and then, after the loop, print the last number, without a comma. (Alternately, one might print the first number before the loop, without a comma, and then print the remaining numbers in the loop, with a comma before each.) For the other issues, we need to see more of your source code. To see why the output is not sorted, we need to see where the output is in your code and to see the sort code. For questions about digits, we need exact copies of input and output.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the sorting works perfectly, I just have the problem with the output of digits, I can't make them differ depending on the input, I have both round numbers and decimal numbers so I need to print them the same I entered them without the extra decimal points. If i put just %.f it works for round numbers, but if I put %.1f it works for decimals but not integers.

Comment: If you provide the requested information, people will help you. If you do not, I predict your question will be closed and likely voted down. Your choice.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I updated it, I'm new to the site and I don't quite know how it works, thank you.

Comment: If your inputs could include `1E-36`, `2.4e+12`, `2322152343299.34531`, `0x1.A395DFP-6`, and so on, then the only reasonable way to get the same output as you had input is to read the numbers as strings (into an array of a structure type, where one element of the structure is a string and the other the double), then convert the strings into `double` values, then sort based on the double values, and then print the strings in sequence.  Valid inputs are far more diverse than any single output format can possibly cope with.

Comment: The code to sort is wrong. Do not provide a part of a program, provide an **entire** program including the definition of `main` and the `#include` statements. Show the **exact text** of the input and the **exact text** of the output. Do not show “1, -2, 3.4,-2.3, 0” as you have in the question unless those commas actually appear in the actual input. If you have commas in the input, the `scanf` you show in the code will not work. Read the information at [mre].

Comment: Rather then adding an edit to say you fixed one of the problems you are asking about, you should simply delete the problem.  Unless someone has already addressed the issue in an answer, in which case you should probably just leave it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to print an array with different digits after the decimal point?
> I just need to print out for example the number 3 as 3, and the number 3.4 only as 3.4 in the same for loop.  (OP)

Use `"%g"` for printing.

Prints like `"%f"` or `"%e"`:

> (`"%g"`) ... is converted in style f or e (or in style F or E in the case of a G conversion specifier), depending on the value converted and the precision....

> Finally, unless the # flag is used, any **trailing zeros are removed from the fractional portion** of the result and the **decimal-point character is removed** if there is no fractional portion remaining.  C17dr § 7.21.6.1 8

---

To print 2.3 as "2.3", "2.30", "+2.3" when the original input text was "2.3", "2.30", "+2.3", read the input as a *stirng* and save it.  [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65744095/how-to-print-an-array-with-different-digits-after-the-decimal-point/65744336?noredirect=1#comment116240261_65744095)